# How do pianists cope with numb fingers?

Tags: piano

I play the piano, and sometimes I get what I call "frozen fingers." My fingers feel slightly cold, but the temperature of the room doesn't influence it. No matter if the room is hot or cold, if it's summer or winter, my fingers sometimes go slightly numb, and it becomes very difficult to play fast pieces like *Rondo Alla Turca*. No matter how hard I try, my fingers just end up playing fast parts unevenly. Does anybody else have this happen to them? If so, how do you cope with it? I've already tried rinsing my hands in hot water, but I feel like that makes it *worse*.

Edit: I've found a couple of links that explained why it's so hard to play fast pieces with cold fingers.

1. [Why is it difficult to play with cold hands?](https://www.pianostreet.com/smf/index.php?topic=56181.0)
2. [How to Get Rid of Cold Hands: Tips for Pianists](https://www.pianocareer.com/piano-health/piano-cold-hands/)

Comment: Does the problem happen in any other setting(s)?

Comment: Welcome! As is usually the case for these physical questions, you might need to talk to a doctor rather than just us. This sounds kind of like nerve issues. Have you talked to a medical person about it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a medical problem.  A medical person will know the correct questions to ask to disambiguate "numb"

Comment: Numbness does not affect speed capability.   You have some other problem, and your description is insufficient to distinguish possible medical issues from basic musical training, I fear.

Comment: Maybe try wristwarmers (e.g. cut off the cuff of a sock and make sure it's not too tight), and also have someone check your posture and set-up, also maybe a cushion would help.  Another idea -- go for a little jog around the block every half hour.  In other words, experiment and then you'll have lots of data to report when you see the doctor.

Comment: It could (!) be the Raynaud syndrome. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raynaud_syndrome)
But in my daily practice, I get numb fingers if I have drunken too less water. Or do you somehow clamp a nerve, e. g. by positioning your arm on an edge?

Comment: @user7427029 Luckily, I don't think it's Raynaud Syndrome. I will take your advice about drinking water, though.